# Cloud datastore namespace deletion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible to delete a namespace (and all subsequent entities) from cloud datastore?

Reading through the docs it seems you can delete entities from namespaces but I couldn't see where to remove the namespace. Wondering if there is the ability to do this from the Google Cloud CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The namespace isn't a data structure unto itself, but is merely metadata that is part of the entities inside it. Technically, once all entities are deleted in a namespace it doesn't exist anymore.

It may take a few days for the stats data to remove it, at which point you'll stop seeing it in Cloud Console, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Thats really useful to know - my boy scout was kicking in ha